# Get item on list in file. I/O operation on closed file error

Tags: python, list

Today I am having trouble with *closed file error*. If any body enlightens me I really appreciate it. In general speaking, I want to get items in a text file list

**1. Q:** Here is my two code, when I try to reach one of the item of the list I always get the same error "I/O operation on closed file"

**1st code:**
I strip and split a text file to list. Finally I want to get for instance: f[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEGfg.jpg)[2]

```
f=map(str.split, open("smpl_list.txt", "r"))
print(f[1][2])
```

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

**2nd code:**

```
c=open ("smp.txt", "r")
d=c.readlines()
print d[1][1]
```

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

**2. Q:** I have a list and already named the columns. And I want to do some simple math with using column name. 
Here is my sample list file,

[image]

For example, I would like to do;

> *function= a+b+c+d*;
>           hello=7, tht=14 etc...

is there a way? How can I solve it? Many thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
I do not want to make a mess and that's why at the beginning I did not paste the whole code. Here is the complete code

```
f=map(str.split, open("smpl_list.txt", "r"))
print(f[1][2])

with open("smpl_list.txt", "r") as m, open ("smpl.txt","w") as n:
    for line in m:
        n.write(line.strip()+"\n")

import pandas as pd
with open ("smp.txt", "w") as r:
    df=pd.read_csv("smpl.txt", sep=" ", header=None, names=["a","b","c","d"])
    print>> r, df
c=open ("smp.txt", "r")
d=c.readlines()
print d[1][1]
```

Well at the end I would like to do some math with a list which is in the a file.

Comment: In what line are these errors being thrown? Your code as posted won't throw this error alone, so it has to be side effects from somewhere else in your code.

Comment: You're opening `smp.txt` in the second line. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I try to open and readlines of the sm.txt file in order to make a list from it

Comment: I posted the whole code, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the error in your second piece of code can't be reproduced, the best library for this kind of stuff is `pandas`. Now, I can't give a specific example because you've pasted an image of your file and not the actual text, but in a perfect world you would structure something like this:

```
hello,tht,yem,nem
1,2,1,1
1,3,4,2
2,4,5,4
3,5,6,7
```

If you did that, then the code would be as easy as this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(<your_file>)
print(df['hello'].sum())
```